# From XeLaTeX's Unicode-math to ConTeXt's typescript

Tags: fonts, context, unicode-math

I search a way to translate the following XeLaTeX's declaration (based on the `unicode-math` package)

```
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine G}
\setsansfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Liberation Sans}
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase,
  ItalicFont=lmmono10-italic.otf,
  BoldFont=lmmonolt10-bold.otf,
  BoldItalicFont=lmmonolt10-boldoblique.otf,
  SmallCapsFont=lmmonocaps10-regular]{lmmono10-regular.otf}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mathup]{linlibertine_r_g.ttf}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mathbfup]{linlibertine_rz_g.ttf}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mathsfup]{liberationsans-regular.ttf}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mathsfit]{liberationsans-italic.ttf}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mathbfsfup]{liberationsans-bold.ttf}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mathbfsfit]{liberationsans-bolditalic.ttf}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mathtt]{lmmono10-italic.otf}
\setmathfont[Scale=MatchLowercase, range=\mathscr]{asana-math.otf}
```

into a ConTeXt's typescript. I succeed to set the serif, sansserif and mono fonts; but I need help for the math settings.

```
\startenvironment liberty
  \starttypescript [liberty]
    \definefontsynonym [Serif] [file:LinLibertine_R_G]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifCaps] [Serif] [features=smallcaps]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic] [file:LinLibertine_RI_G]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifSlanted] [SerifItalic]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [file:LinLibertine_RZ_G]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldItalic] [file:LinLibertine_RZI_G]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldSlanted] [SerifBoldItalic]

    \definefontsynonym [Sans] [file:LiberationSans-Regular]
    \definefontsynonym [SansCaps] [Sans] [features=smallcaps]
    \definefontsynonym [SansItalic] [file:LiberationSans-Italic]
    \definefontsynonym [SansSlanted] [SansItalic]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBold] [file:LiberationSans-Bold]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBoldItalic] [file:LiberationSans-BoldItalic]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBoldSlanted] [SansBoldItalic]

    \definetypeface [liberty] [rm] [serif] [liberty] [default]
    \definetypeface [liberty] [ss] [sans] [liberty] [default] [rscale=0.816]
    \definetypeface [liberty] [tt] [mono] [modern] [default]
    \definetypeface [liberty] [mm] [math] [times] [default] [rscale=0.958]
  \stoptypescript
  \setupbodyfont[liberty, 10pt]
\stopenvironment
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: Does someone know what is the equivalent of `Scale=MatchLowercase`? The `rscale`s I used come from the log file produced by XeLaTeX.

EDIT. As suggested in a comment, this is a beginning of a fallback-based solution which, surprisingly, doesn't work.

```
\startenvironment liberty
  \starttypescript [serif] [liberty]
    \definefontsynonym [Serif] [file:LinLibertine_R]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifCaps] [Serif] [features=smallcaps]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic] [file:LinLibertine_RI]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifSlanted] [SerifItalic]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [file:LinLibertine_RZ]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldItalic] [file:LinLibertine_RZI]
    \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldSlanted] [SerifBoldItalic]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [sans] [liberty]
    \definefontsynonym [Sans] [file:LiberationSans-Regular]
    \definefontsynonym [SansCaps] [Sans] [features=smallcaps]
    \definefontsynonym [SansItalic] [file:LiberationSans-Italic]
    \definefontsynonym [SansSlanted] [SansItalic]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBold] [file:LiberationSans-Bold]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBoldItalic] [file:LiberationSans-BoldItalic]
    \definefontsynonym [SansBoldSlanted] [SansBoldItalic]
  \stoptypescript

  \starttypescript [math] [liberty]
    \definefontfallback [asserif] [Serif] [0x0030-0x0039] % Digits
    \definefontfallback [asserif] [Serif] [0x0041-0x005a] % Latin capital letters
    \definefontfallback [asserif] [Serif] [0x0061-0x007a] % Latin small letters
    \definefontsynonym [MathRoman] [file:texgyretermes-math] [fallbacks=asserif]
  \stoptypescript

  \definetypeface [liberty] [rm] [serif] [liberty] [default]
  \definetypeface [liberty] [ss] [sans] [liberty] [default] [rscale=0.816]
  \definetypeface [liberty] [tt] [mono] [modern] [default]
  \definetypeface [liberty] [mm] [math] [liberty] [default] %[rscale=0.958]
  \setupbodyfont[liberty, 10pt]
\stopenvironment
```

Comment: There are very few ConTeXt font experts on this site. You may be better off asking this question on [the context mailing list](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Mailing_Lists)

Comment: AFAIK (but I may be wrong here as I don't know simplefont module provide such support), something like this is not supported out of the box in ConTeXt. ConTeXt assumes that you will use a unicode math font; the only way to support mixing alphabets from different fonts is to create your own virtual unicode math font. There are some examples of how to do this in `math-ttv.lua` and `math-vfu.lua` files in the distribution. The consensus in the ConTeXt community seems to be that it is not worth spending the effort to design an interface around this, as we'll have more opentype math fonts soon.

Comment: Some examples for virtual math fonts can be found in [this article](http://www.ntg.nl/maps/38/05.pdf) from MAPS. Also, if you want to substitute certain ranges with characters from different fonts via typescript, you are looking for [font fallbacks](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/font-col.mkvi#l14).

Comment: @phg I have edited the question. I try to write a fallback-based solution but I need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.
Beware, you will need a recent version of ConTeXt.
In the following example, I will use Baskervald, Corbel and Ubuntu Mono
instead of Libertine, Liberation and Latin Modern Mono.
Our mixed mathematical font will be based on Pagella Math.

First of all, one should know the code of mathematical glyphs
within an Opentype mathematical font.
They are for example in the character table of MS Word.
For Pagella Math we have:

- 0x30-0x39 = 0-9
- 0x41-0x5A = upright roman A-Z
- 0x61-0x7A = upright roman a-z
- 0x1D434-0x1D44D = italic roman A-Z
- 0x1D44E-0x1D467 = italic roman a-z
- 0x1D400-0x1D419 = upright bold roman A-Z
- 0x1D41A-0x1D433 = upright bold roman a-z
- 0x1D468-0x1D481 = italic bold roman A-Z
- 0x1D482-0x1D49B = italic bold roman a-z
- 0x1D5A0-0x1D5B9 = upright sans serif A-Z
- 0x1D5BA-0x1D5D3 = upright sans serif a-z
- 0x1D608-0x1D621 = italic sans serif A-Z
- 0x1D622-0x1D63B = italic sans serif a-z
- 0x1D5D4-0x1D5ED = upright bold sans serif A-Z
- 0x1D5EE-0x1D607 = upright bold sans serif a-z
- 0x1D63C-0x1D655 = italic bold sans serif A-Z
- 0x1D656-0x1D66F = italic bold sans serif a-z
- 0x1D670-0x1D689 = upright mono A-Z
- 0x1D68A-0x1D6A3 = upright mono a-z

Now we use the fallback mechanism and the offset option to do the mapping:

```
\startenvironment liberty
    % 0x30-0x39 = 0-9 within both Pagella Math and Baskervald
    \definefontfallback [baskervaldmath] [file:BaskervaldADFStd] [0x30-0x39] [force=yes]
    % 0x41-0x5A = upright roman A-Z within both Pagella Math and Baskervald
    \definefontfallback [baskervaldmath] [file:BaskervaldADFStd] [0x41-0x5A] [force=yes]
    % 0x61-0x7A = upright roman a-z within both Pagella Math and Baskervald
    \definefontfallback [baskervaldmath] [file:BaskervaldADFStd] [0x61-0x7A] [force=yes]
    % 0x1D434-0x1D44D = italic roman A-Z
    \definefontfallback [baskervaldmath] [file:BaskervaldADFStd-Italic] [0x41-0x5A] [offset=0x1D434-0x1D44D, force=yes]
    % 0x1D44E-0x1D467 = italic roman a-z
    \definefontfallback [baskervaldmath] [file:BaskervaldADFStd-Italic] [0x61-0x7A] [offset=0x1D44E-0x1D467, force=yes]
    % 0x1D400-0x1D419 = upright bold roman A-Z
    \definefontfallback [baskervaldmath] [file:BaskervaldADFStd-Bold] [0x41-0x5A] [offset=0x1D400-0x1D419, force=yes]
    % etc.
    % Type script
    \starttypescript [serif] [liberty]
        \definefontsynonym [Serif] [file:BaskervaldADFStd]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifCaps] [Serif] [features=smallcaps]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifItalic] [file:BaskervaldADFStd-Italic]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifSlanted] [SerifItalic]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifBold] [file:BaskervaldADFStd-Bold]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldItalic] [file:BaskervaldADFStd-BoldItalic]
        \definefontsynonym [SerifBoldSlanted] [SerifBoldItalic]
    \stoptypescript
    \starttypescript [sans] [liberty]
        \definefontsynonym [Sans] [file:corbel]
        \definefontsynonym [SansCaps] [Sans] [features=smallcaps]
        \definefontsynonym [SansItalic] [file:corbeli]
        \definefontsynonym [SansSlanted] [SansItalic]
        \definefontsynonym [SansBold] [file:corbelb]
        \definefontsynonym [SansBoldItalic] [file:corbelz]
        \definefontsynonym [SansBoldSlanted] [SansBoldItalic]
    \stoptypescript
    \starttypescript [mono] [liberty]
        \definefontsynonym [Mono] [file:UbuntuMono-R]
        \definefontsynonym [MonoCaps] [Mono] [features=smallcaps]
        \definefontsynonym [MonoItalic] [file:UbuntuMono-RI]
        \definefontsynonym [MonoSlanted] [MonoItalic]
        \definefontsynonym [MonoBold] [file:UbuntuMono-B]
        \definefontsynonym [MonoBoldItalic] [file:UbuntuMono-BI]
        \definefontsynonym [MonoBoldSlanted] [MonoBoldItalic]
    \stoptypescript
    \starttypescript [math] [liberty]
        \definefontsynonym [MathRoman] [file:texgyrepagella-math] [fallbacks=baskervaldmath]
    \stoptypescript
    \definetypeface [liberty] [rm] [serif] [liberty] [default] [features=default]
    \definetypeface [liberty] [ss] [sans] [liberty] [default] [features=default, rscale=0.95]
    \definetypeface [liberty] [tt] [mono] [liberty] [default] [features=default, rscale=0.88]
    \definetypeface [liberty] [mm] [math] [liberty] [default] [features=default]
    \setupbodyfont [liberty, 12pt]
\stopenvironment
```

Answer (score 2):

for Libertine there is already a typescript defined. To get the TeXGyre Pagella Math, which 
looks nice with Libertine, load Pagella as first:

```
\setupbodyfont[pagella]
\setupbodyfont[libertine,12pt]

\starttext
foo $bar$
\stoptext
```

the fonts are:

```
voss@shania:~> pdffonts zz.pdf
name                              type        encoding   emb sub uni object ID
--------------------------------- ----------- -------------- --- --- ---------
RSSLOW+LinLibertineO              CID Type 0C Identity-H yes yes yes     18  0
TQYEHR+TeXGyrePagellaMath-Regular CID Type 0C Identity-H yes yes yes     19  0
```